# Repositioning with Drag and Drop

Tags: javascript, html

I have a simple drag and drop where you move an image from one box to another. Whenever you drop the image to another box, it auto-aligns. Although, it auto-aligns the image outside of the box. Here's my code:

```js
function allowDrop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev) {
    ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
}

function drop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
    ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
}
```

```css
#div1, #div2 {
    float: left;
    width: 35px;
    height: 35px;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div id="div1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
  
  <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQDBBSFnyl2fRlVY1ct1E6t5rUIFsu8JWmKeTrS9o1nnTigCOfI2g" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="drag1" width="55" height="55">
  
</div>

<div id="div2" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Remove the padding: 10px; and increase width and height by 20px.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to remove your `padding` and adjust the `height` and the `width`

```js
function allowDrop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev) {
    ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
}

function drop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
    ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
}
```

```css
#div1, #div2 {
    float: left;
    width: 55px;
    height: 55px;
    margin: 10px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div id="div1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
  
  <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQDBBSFnyl2fRlVY1ct1E6t5rUIFsu8JWmKeTrS9o1nnTigCOfI2g" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="drag1" width="55" height="55">
  
</div>

<div id="div2" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You made the drop area divs too small in your css. If you match them to the size of the image it aligns it correctly

```js
function allowDrop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev) {
    ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
}

function drop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
    ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
}
```

```css
#div1, #div2 {
    float: left;
    width: 55px;
    height: 55px;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div id="div1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
  
  <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQDBBSFnyl2fRlVY1ct1E6t5rUIFsu8JWmKeTrS9o1nnTigCOfI2g" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="drag1" width="55" height="55">
  
</div>

<div id="div2" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function allowDrop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev) {
    ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
}

function drop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
    ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
}
```

```css
#div1, #div2 {
    float: left;
    width: 55px;
    height: 55px;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 0px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div id="div1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
  
  <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQDBBSFnyl2fRlVY1ct1E6t5rUIFsu8JWmKeTrS9o1nnTigCOfI2g" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="drag1" width="55" height="55">
  
</div>

<div id="div2" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
```